# Задание аргумента по умолчанию в Python

Tags: python, аргументы

Хочу чтобы программа на Python имела два способа вывода результата: в файл или  прямо в командную строку.
Для этого добавил аргумент output. Но хочется, чтобы аргумент output был необязательным. Т.е чтобы вывод в командную строку был по умолчанию. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли более подходящий способ для этого?

Вот способ, который я сейчас использую

```
try:
   program_name, mode, input_alg, input_word, output = argv
except ValueError:
   program_name, mode, input_alg, input_word = argv
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program_name, mode, input_alg, input_word, *rest = argv

if rest:
    output = rest[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x = 0) :
    print(x)
```

переменная `x` в функции `f` стала не обязательной, и по умолчанию равно 0